# npm run build failed on .png | react npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, package

I need help to use .png files in my react npm package. If i run "npm run storybook", everything works fine. only if i try to run "npm run build", i get the following error.

```
 npm run build

> portshare-frontend-libary-components@0.1.0 build
> tsdx build

@rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`. 
@rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`. 
✓ Creating entry file 1.2 secs
Error: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
at D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\src\image\placeholder.png:1:0
```

maybe someone could tell me, what i need to install or what config i need to add, so it will work.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsdx watch",
    "build": "tsdx build",
    "test": "tsdx test --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "tsdx lint",
    "prepare": "tsdx build",
    "size": "size-limit",
    "analyze": "size-limit --why",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "tsdx lint"
    }
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  },
  "module": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.esm.js",
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.cjs.production.min.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.esm.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    }
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "^8.2.4",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.5",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "portshare-frontend-libary-objects": "^1.0.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.13.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.4",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "size-limit": "^8.2.4",
    "storybook": "^7.0.21",
    "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```

and this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  // see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig to better understand tsconfigs
  "include": ["src", "types"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    // output .d.ts declaration files for consumers
    "declaration": true,
    // output .js.map sourcemap files for consumers
    "sourceMap": true,
    // match output dir to input dir. e.g. dist/index instead of dist/src/index
    "rootDir": "./src",
    // stricter type-checking for stronger correctness. Recommended by TS
    "strict": true,
    // linter checks for common issues
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // noUnused* overlap with @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars, can disable if duplicative
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    // use Node's module resolution algorithm, instead of the legacy TS one
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // transpile JSX to React.createElement
    "jsx": "react",
    // interop between ESM and CJS modules. Recommended by TS
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // significant perf increase by skipping checking .d.ts files, particularly those in node_modules. Recommended by TS
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // error out if import and file system have a casing mismatch. Recommended by TS
    "forceConsistentCasing
```